# Apache RewriteRule to treat images, css and js files as normal

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, rewrite

i need to set up an apache RewriteRule in order to have this behavior:

```
example.com/foo => index.php?module=foo&action=&args=
example.com/foo/bar => index.php?module=foo&action=bar&args=
example.com/foo/bar/baz => index.php?module=foo&action=bar&args=baz
example.com/foo/bar/baz/foobaz => index.php?module=foo&action=bar&args=baz/foobaz
```

I wroted this regex:

```
RewriteRule ^(.[^/]*)(\/)?(.[^/]+)?(\/)?(.+)?$ index.php?module=$1&action=$3&args=$5 [L,QSA]
```

It works well, i only need to tell apache to ignore all urls that end with some specific estension (for example, .jpg, .png, .css, .js, .gif, etc..); Those should be treated as normal, e.g. `example.com/css/style.css` should show the CSS file (is it exists).

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to get around it is this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.[^/]*)(\/)?(.[^/]+)?(\/)?(.+)?$ index.php?module=$1&action=$3&args=$5 [L,QSA]
```

That tells apache to not run the rule if the file is a real file on the system that can be served up.. Now you if you want to do it for just image/css/js files you could probably do

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.*).(js|jpg|css|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.[^/]*)(\/)?(.[^/]+)?(\/)?(.+)?$ index.php?module=$1&action=$3&args=$5 [L,QSA]
```

That one is untested but you get the idea.

Comment: +1 ... but the second RewriteCond regexp would be more precise if the period preceding the file extension were escaped.

Comment: Im already using the first rule; In fact in my case the problems come when files doesnt exists!
I'll try the second regex!